# Tree View WIKI replacement solution for SharePoint like Confluence?

Tags: sharepoint, active-directory, jira, confluence, sharepoint-wiki

I keep my Process Documents on SVN and I want to create a Wiki page includes the information about these files. We use SharePoint in the company for basic document sharing and team sites. As it is mentioned in
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/256407/what-are-your-biggest-complaints-about-sharepoint SharePoint Wiki lacks of usability. I need an easy to use wiki tool which is capable of showing the content like WikiPedia contents and it would be great if I could have the SharePoint tree view  and Active Directory authentication also. I googled it and found Atlassian's Confluence and it seems that this product is capable of the requirements. We use Jira for issue tracking, so we can use it's reporting in dashboards. I need and it has a Wiki part which displays wiki pages in tree view. It should be like [http://www.atlassian.com/software/confluence/images/tour/full/page_tree.png http://www.atlassian.com/software/confluence/images/tour/full/page_tree.png](http://www.atlassian.com/software/confluence/images/tour/full/page_tree.png)

Does anyone used Confluence or have an idea for other products which meets my requirements

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you considered our Confluence Sharepoint connector? It sounds like that's what your after, it will allow you to use Sharepoint for all the other features, but use Confluence as your wiki http://www.atlassian.com/sharepoint/.

Seeing that you already use Jira, you could use Confluence and leverage off some level of integration between the two products.

Let me know if you have any questions.

Sherif Mansour (@sherifmansour)
Confluence Product Manager

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I will check for the Confluence connector with our product.